# URL Routing in PHP : url routes ony to 404-Not-Found page

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

I have a php project in htdocs folder named "das-xampp". The index file in the root directory works as a router. I have another index.php inside views.
so the structure is as below:

```
das-xamp
|__index.php
|__views
   |__index.php
   |__about-us.php
   |__404-Not_Found.php
```

So whenever someone types 'localhost/das-xampp' it should re-route the user to the index inside 'views/index.php'
My root index(the one that works as a router) is as follows:

```
<?php

$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');
parse_url($path, PHP_URL_PATH);
$routes = [

''=> 'views/index.php',
'about-us' => 'views/about-us.php'


];
if (array_key_exists($path,$routes)) {
     require $routes[$path];
}else {
    require 'views/404-Not-Found.php';
}


?>
```

The thing is whenever I type in 'localhost/das-xampp'(after turning on apache and mysql), the not-found php comes up. Even when I type 'localhost/das-xampp/about-us' manually Object not found is shown.

This doens't happen if I use

```
"php -S localhost:<some_digit>"
```

All my view works fine.

[not-found page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wOnGe.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with .htaccess file. I didn't include an .htaccess file which will re-route according to the routings I had in index.php file(the one in the root directory).
I'm posting the .htaccess code below

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /das/index.php [L]
```